# Check if speech packages is already in android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

Hello i'm building an app that uses speech recognition, my intention is, that user can use the app without internet, so for he do it he need download an language package inside his smartphone.

**1 - Is possible check if user already has the package inside the phone?** 
**2 - Can i show the speech packages system configuration to the user ( like wifi or gps configuration )?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for TTS installed . Use this code from your activity

```
Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
        checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);

        checkTTSIntent.putExtra(
                TextToSpeech.Engine.EXTRA_CHECK_VOICE_DATA_FOR,
                Locale.getDefault());
        startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
```

In your onActivityResult add this code which checks if the tts engine is available or not

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_FAIL) {
            //TTS is not installed for the default language
        }

        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {

            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "TTS Engine Data for default language is installed ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

       //TTS for default language not installed.check for other languages 
            if (data != null) {
                ArrayList<String> availableLanguages = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(TextToSpeech.Engine.EXTRA_AVAILABLE_VOICES);

                if (availableLanguages.isEmpty()) {
                    // no language data available, prompt for install
                    showDialog();
                } else {
                    // some language data is available, create TTS instance

                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "TTS Engine Data for default language is installed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }

        }
```